# filter listview using searchview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, filter, searchview

I have a list for that i want to add search function using search view. i have sqlite database and two fragments in which i am adding products and in another i am displaying the products in list view. i want to filter this list. how can i achieve this? i have searched many links but by searching all i have got confused..I am new to android so plz anyone can help? your help will be appretiated.. thnk u..

this is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

     Toolbar mToolbar;
    public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    FrameLayout mContentFrame;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private static final String PREFERENCES_FILE = "mymaterialapp_settings";
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition;
    public ArrayList<Item> arrayList;
    public DBHandler db;
    ArrayList<Item> array_data;
   public SearchView searchView;
    ListView listview;
   public ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer);


        setUpToolbar();
        arrayList=new ArrayList<Item>();
        array_data=new ArrayList<Item>();
        db = new DBHandler(this);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer);

        mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readSharedSetting(this, PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
        firstTimeFrag();
        setUpNavDrawer();

        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mContentFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.nav_contentframe);

        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                Fragment newFragment;
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_item_1:
                        newFragment = new AddStock();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_contentframe, newFragment);
                      //  transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                        mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_item_2:
                        newFragment = new ViewStock();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_contentframe, newFragment);
                     //   transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                        mCurrentSelectedPosition = 1;
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return true;
                }
            }
        });
        //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_contentframe, fragment).commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, 0);
        Menu menu = mNavigationView.getMenu();
        menu.getItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition).setChecked(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(this,R.menu.menu_main);
     }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:

            case R.id.search_view:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setUpToolbar() {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (mToolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        }
    }

    private void setUpNavDrawer() {
        if (mToolbar != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
            mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            });
        }

        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
            saveSharedSetting(this, PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "true");
        }

    }

    public static void saveSharedSetting(Context ctx, String settingName, String settingValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString(settingName, settingValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String readSharedSetting(Context ctx, String settingName, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPref.getString(settingName, defaultValue);
    }
    private void firstTimeFrag(){

            Fragment fr = new ViewStock();
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_contentframe, fr);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
}


this is my item class

public class Item  {
    public int id;
    public String item_name;
    public String item_desc;
    public String item_qty;

    public Item(){}
    public Item(int id ,String item_name,String item_desc,String item_qty) {
        super();
        this.item_name = item_name;
        this.item_desc = item_desc;
        this.item_qty = item_qty;
    }

    public Item(String item_name,String item_desc, String item_qty){
        this.item_name = item_name;
        this.item_desc=item_desc;
        this.item_qty = item_qty;
    }

    public int getID(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(int id){
        this.id= id;
    }
    public String getItem_name(){
        return item_name;
    }

    public void setItem_name(String item_name)
    {
        this.item_name=item_name;
    }

    public String getItem_desc()
    {
        return  item_desc;
    }
    public  void setItem_desc(String item_desc)
    {
        this.item_desc=item_desc;
    }
    public String getItem_qty()
    {
        return  item_qty;
    }
    public void setItem_qty(String item_qty) {
        this.item_qty = item_qty;
    }
}

this is my ItemAdapter

public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> implements Filterable {

        Context context;

 //   ValueFilter valueFilter;
    ArrayList<Item> mStringFilterList;
    ArrayList<Item> items;


    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                                ArrayList<Item>  items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items=items;
        mStringFilterList=items;
    }

      public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        public Item getItem(int position) {
            return items.get(position);
        }

    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            Item rowItem = getItem(position);
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

                holder.txtItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_name);
                holder.txtItemDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_desc);
                holder.txtItemQty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_qty);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.txtItemName.setText(rowItem.getItem_name());
            holder.txtItemDesc.setText(rowItem.getItem_desc());
            holder.txtItemQty.setText(rowItem.getItem_qty());

            return convertView;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtItemName;
            TextView txtItemDesc;
            TextView txtItemQty;
        }
}

this is my view stock fragment


public class ViewStock extends Fragment {

    public ViewStock() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_stock, container, false);
        MainActivity act = (MainActivity) this.getActivity();
        act.listview = (ListView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.list);
        act.listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        act.array_data = new ArrayList<Item>();
        // Context mCtx = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

     //   ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, act.arrayList);
       // listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        act.db = new DBHandler(getActivity());
        ArrayList<Item> item_array_from_db = act.db.Get_items();

        for (int i = 0; i < item_array_from_db.size(); i++) {

            int idno = item_array_from_db.get(i).getID();
            String name = item_array_from_db.get(i).getItem_name();
            String desc = item_array_from_db.get(i).getItem_desc();
            String qty = item_array_from_db.get(i).getItem_qty();
            Item cnt = new Item();
            cnt.setID(idno);
            cnt.setItem_name(name);
            cnt.setItem_desc(desc);
            cnt.setItem_qty(qty);

            act.array_data.add(cnt);
        }
        act.db.close();
      act.adapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item,
                act.array_data);
        act.listview.setAdapter(act.adapter);
        act.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return rootview;
    }
}

this is my database

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "stock";
    private static final String TABLE_ITEMS = "items";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "itemname";
    private static final String KEY_DESC = "itemdesc";
    private static final String KEY_QTY = "itemqty";
    private final ArrayList<Item> array_list = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ITEMS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DESC + " TEXT," + KEY_QTY + " INTEGER" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ITEMS);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void Add_Item(Item item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, item.getItem_name());
        values.put(KEY_DESC, item.getItem_desc());
        values.put(KEY_QTY, item.getItem_qty());

        db.insert(TABLE_ITEMS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }


   Item Get_Item(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_ITEMS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                        KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_QTY }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Item item = new Item(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return item;
    }


    public ArrayList<Item> Get_items() {
        try {
            array_list.clear();

            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Item item = new Item();
                    item.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    item.setItem_name(cursor.getString(1));
                    item.setItem_desc(cursor.getString(2));
                    item.setItem_qty(cursor.getString(3));

                    array_list.add(item);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return array_list;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("all_contact", "" + e);
        }

        return array_list;
    }  
}

this is my view stock layout

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.example.owner.stock.ViewStock">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="#ff45f3ff">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_item_name"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txt_item_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="0.33" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_item_desc"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txt_item_desc"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="0.33" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_item_qty"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/txt_item_qty"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="0.33" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="462dp"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

plz can anyone help me out for this?? I need to know can we use filter class for sqlite? and i have a fragment in that i have my list so how the search activity will be called??

Answer (score 0):

You can use Filter instance from the `ArrayAdapter` to filter the items.
Your code can be like this-

```
mCurFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(mCurFilter);
```

and can be fired from the

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
```

Method of implemented `SerachView`.
For the detail you can have a look on the [API Demo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LoaderCustom.java).

Comment: yes i have tried to use this way. but when i enter in search view it dose not filter the list after first character but when i submit the whole text it gives filtered list. what can b the reason for this

Comment: Is your list having large number of items?

Comment: dose it give problem for large number of items??

Comment: It might take time for very large number of data.

Comment: You you are quarrying from the sqlite? Are using proper like patterns?

Comment: i have put my filter have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Item> filterList = new ArrayList<Item>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                    if ( (mStringFilterList.get(i).getItem_name())
                            .contains(constraint.toString())) {

                        Item item = new Item(mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getItem_name() ,  mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getItem_desc() ,  mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getItem_qty());

                        filterList.add(item);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                results.values = mStringFilterList;
            }
            return results;

        }

        @Override
        public void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                   FilterResults results) {
            items = (ArrayList<Item>) results.values;
               notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

this is my filter